# How can I install persistent Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: usb-creator

i can't install persistent ubuntu 13.04 on my 4gb using Universal usb installer.
it acts as live usb not persistent usb it gives me setup every boot.
i used to install persistent ubuntu using Universal USB installer