# Toram option and persistence on live USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I created an Ubuntu live USB using UNetbootin. I also know that the to RAM option would speed up the OS in exchange of RAM. But when I do append `persistence` with the `toram` to the boot options, it doesn't save my changes, but it does boot to ram because the `free` reports about 800+ MB usage -- just enough for the iso. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Take a look at the screenshot in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/338195/how-can-i-install-persistent-ubuntu-13-04/338213#338213) to the question: How can I install persistent Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: I have done that and persistence works only without the `toram` option.

Comment: It seems as if the Ubuntu live USB is running entirely from RAM, and it doesn't even write any changes back to the USB flash drive on which you installed the Ubuntu live USB.

Comment: Maybe that is why it seemed that data persistence does not work.

Comment: I've got another live USB distro called Lightweight Portable Security that also runs entirely from RAM, and I get the same results as you do. Every time I boot it, it starts over like a fresh live USB, and it doesn't save a thing.

Comment: What is persistence switch?

Comment: A better question might be what is "presistence" switch @K7AAY is pointing out that according to your post you may have made a spelling error in your boot options